# Can you check if validation rules exist / are valid? [Laravel]

Tags: php, laravel, validation

My app has a custom fields functionality: the user can create additional fields for its products.

Ex: the user sells food and wants to add a date field for the product's expiration date.

The expiration date must be greater than today's date. To achieve this, the user has a set of validation rules he can select from the frontend. The rules are sent through the request and stored in the database. When the user creates a new product, the validation rules are retrieved from the database and applied to that field (ex: expiration_date).

How can I make sure that the user cannot tamper with the request to try and add invalid validation rules?

Is there a way to check that the validation rules are valid/exist so that the app doesn't try to apply invalid rules and throws an error?

Comment: You need to validate your validation rules. So you know what rules you want to use, provide a list of options to your end user. Then compare (validate) the value from the request with an array of accepted values.

Comment: That works for simple validation rules. But how can I do that for the rules that require a parameter (ex: size, min, max, starts_with, etc...)?

Comment: You could create custom rules for those, passing in the parameters and building your rule set dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using regex to validate all validation rules.

Available validation rules:
accepted,
active_url,
alpha,
alpha_dash,
array,
boolean,
date,
declined,
distinct,
email:,
integer,
ip,
ipv4
ipv6,
mac_address,
json,
required,
nullable,
string,
url,
after:,
before:,
after_or_equal:,
before_or_equal:,
between:,
digits:,
digits_between:,
ends_with:,
starts_with:,
min:,
max:,
multiple_of:,
size:

This is the regex:

```regex
/accepted|nullable|active_url|alpha(_dash)?|array|size:[0-9]{1,9}
|(max|min|multiple_of):(-?[0-9]{1,9})|(ends|starts)_with:([A-z]+,)*([A-z]+)
|digits_between:([0-9]{1,2}),([0-9]{1,2})|digits:(-?[0-9]{1,2})
|between:(-?[0-9]{1,9}),(-?[0-9]{1,9})|boolean|date
|(after|before)(_or_equal)?:(today|[0-9]{4}-((1[0-2])|(0?[1-9]))-((3[01])|([0-2]?[0-9])))
|declined|distinct(:(strict|ignore_case))?
|email(:(((rfc|dns|strict|spoof|filter),){1,4})?(rfc|dns|strict|spoof|filter))?
|integer|ip(v[46])?|mac_address|json|required|string|url/
```